# Why is this MySQL query performing slowly despite correct indexing?

Tags: mysql, index

I have a large MyISAM table A (500m entries) that connects two other tables B,C with a n:m relation.

So my table A looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (
  `id_b` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_c` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `Uniqueness` (`id_c`,`id_b`),
  KEY `id_b` (`id_b`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Every entity in B is related to 1-12 entities in C with an average of 8 and a mode of 10.

Every entitiy in C is related to 100-500 entities in B.

Now for a specific entitiy c I want a list of all other entities in C that it is connected to through B and how many entities in B they are connect through.
Or more directly: I have a specific c, that is connected 100-500 b's which are each connected to a handful of other entities in C. I want to know which C's the b's are connect with, and how often.

My simplified query looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), OtherA.id_c FROM A
INNER JOIN A OtherA
ON OtherA.id_b = A.id_b
WHERE A.id_c=[MY_SPECIFIC_C_ID]
GROUP BY OtherA.id_c
```

And takes over a second to execute. As described above, the inner join should yield at max a few thousand results and the group should reduce it to a few hundred. As far as I can tell I indexed correctly, so I am confused why this query is taking so long.

EXPLAIN yields the following result:

```
row1
id--------------1
select_type-----SIMPLE
table-----------A
type------------ref
possible_keys---Uniqueness,id_b
key-------------Uniqueness
key_len---------5
ref-------------const
rows------------462
Extra-----------Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
row2
id--------------1
select_type-----SIMPLE
table-----------OtherA
type------------ref
possible_keys---id_b
key-------------id_b
key_len---------5
ref-------------THISDB.A.id_b
rows------------8
Extra-----------Using where
```